# js flv player fullscreen option

Tags: javascript

I am developing my custom video control using jquery  , javascript. for that i choose js flv player without any control bar,
so I almost developed its control bar and all the option using its listner javascript object, but now there is no full screen method in that js flv player.

any body know how can I control the full screen option, I am using the following flv player

[flv-player.net](http://flv-player.net/)

Comment: any help, would be appriciated

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this, I too am having the same issue.. I thought about sending the key press F but this only works in IE...

Comment: yes, i my case when user click full screen ,i expand div to full screen

Comment: You should write your answer for IE below. your answer will be welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per their [FAQs](http://flv-player.net/help/#faq4):

> Fullscreen only works with **Flash Player newer than 9.0.16**.

It is controlled by `showfullscreen` option which clearly [mentions](http://flv-player.net/players/maxi/documentation/) that it only works with Flash v9.0.16 or higher.

An alternative is to switch to [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) plugin. I've used it in a current project with great success. It provides many more options and supports mobile devices too (iPad etc).

Here's a Flowplayer demo for switching to fullscreen: [Forcing to view the video in fullscreen mode](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/events/toggle-fullscreen.html)
Another one: [Custom Fullscreen action with overlay](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/tools/fake-fullscreen.html)

Comment: Be sure to add <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> to get the full screen button to operate properly.  At this point, unless you are supporting a legacy system like myself, you should pick from any of the modern players like flowplayer, mediaelement, videojs etc.  Far better documentation and features.

Answer (score 3):

The best player to use would be [videojs](http://videojs.com/). Really flexible. I have used it in one of my projects and i would recommend this for you. Got a full screen option by default. Uses js and no flash needed at all.

Comment: This is a nice recommendation, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: ah, it can do fullscreen as well, didn't see that. Fair enough

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. but i am using js flv player, which i have already developed and working fine, there is one thing missing full screen,

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/js-flv-player-fullscreen-option/

**NOTE:** as explaned by the author of the FLash Player [here](http://flv-player.net/help/#faq4)

> - Fullscreen only works with Flash Player newer than 9.0.16.
> - Fullscreen is not compatible with wmode transparency.

so we can at least **simulate** the full screen for those that not support it by using the `$(document)` **width / height** ( or whatever you want ) to fix the player size: and make use of the `wmode` property; this way you can use **CSS** `position` and `z-index` to display the controls over the flash player.

**UTILS:** [Detecting Flash Player versions and embedding SWF files with SWFObject](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html)